# minimum code to have one table row vertically aligned to middle, and another to the top?

Tags: html, css

I have a table, let's say with 3 rows,
I want the first two to be aligned vertically to the top, and second one to be vertically aligned to the middle.

If I try to define:

```
td {vertical-align:top}
tr.middle {vertical-align:middle}
```

and in the html, assign `class="middle"` to the relevant `<tr>`,
it doesn't work, as the td definition would persist.

only way i've managed to do is is to define

```
td.top {vertical-align:top}
td.middle {vertical-align:middle}
```

and then assign the relevant class to every single td, which is too much code.

any way to do this with minimum code?

Comment: Using your current solution, it's not hard to assign the class to every `td`, it can be done in one line with JavaScript. By "too much code" do you mean  assigning the `class` within your HTML takes too much typing? Or are you just looking for a better way to do this?

Comment: better way, my way is just too messy and not elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this, no need to edit your HTML or add classes.

```
tr:nth-child(1) td {vertical-align:top;}
tr:nth-child(2) td {vertical-align:middle;}
tr:nth-child(3) td {vertical-align:bottom;}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/v68ao3pv/1

If you need IE8 support:

```
tr:first-child td           {vertical-align:top;}
tr:first-child + tr td      {vertical-align:middle;}
tr:first-child + tr + tr td {vertical-align:bottom;}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/v68ao3pv/2/show

Comment: Thanks! that's a nice method but I'm looking for something that would work on IE8 as well.

Comment: @rockyraw I added another method that will work in IE8.

Comment: cool, thanks! so for each additional row I would add another `+ tr` I suppose

Comment: @rockyraw You are welcome, glad to be of help to you. If you want to support IE8 with this approach, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. You can use Descendant selectors. That means, you assign the class “top” to the first tr and the class “middle” to the second one and write in CSS:

```
.top td{vertical-align:top}
.middle td{vertical-align: middle}
//     ↑
// THIS space is important.
```

So it selects all table cells within an element with the top/middle class. This is something very practical which you can use quite often.
More about CSS selectors on the [website of the W3 Consortium](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using your current CSS, make the `.middle` rule selector more specific:

```
td {vertical-align:top}
tr.middle td {vertical-align:middle}
```

In this case, all `td` will align to the top by default and the more specific selector will force all the cells in the `.middle` rows to align to the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't get much more minimum than this **Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/sqhxqdck/

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, all you really need is:

```
tr.top {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Due to the cascading nature of cascading style sheets.

Comment: Your solution is slightly fragile because is you specify the `vertical-align` property to the `td` rule, it will over-ride the rule for `tr.top`.  As an example, consider the following http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/sqhxqdck/1/

Comment: He said minimum amount of code, not "kinda small amount of code with some faux-safety in mind."  Of course any CSS is going to break if you overwrite it with more specificity (Quick Reference: http://cssspecificity.com/).  Here's your answer breaking too in an equally trivial way: http://jsfiddle.net/ag2cgcd0/